# How to disconnect private link from Azure Front Door Origin via Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-front-door, azure-private-link

We have deployed an Azure front door premium instance connecting to an App Service instance over private endpoints using Az powershell, namely `New-AzFrontDoorCdnOrigin` then approving with `Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection`.
This all works fine.

However, how can this link be removed via preferably Az powershell?

It is as simple as unchecking the "Enable private link service" in the portal, but the Az powershell documentation is unclear to me here.

Things I've tried:

- Using `Update-AzFrontDoorCdnOrigin`: specifying a `SharedPrivateLinkResourceStatus` of Removed or Disconnected does nothing.
- Using `Update-AzFrontDoorCdnOrigin`: `PrivateLinkId` of empty or null is not allowed.
- Using `Remove-AzPrivateEndpointConnection`.  This removes the connection at the app service, but front door is not aware of the change in state and stops routing traffic to the app service until you manually uncheck the "Enable private link service" box on the origin.

Current workaround is

- Create a second temporary origin in the origin group (so that I don't have to disconnect the origin group from the route, etc)
- Delete the origin with the private link
- Recreate the origin (pref is to have origin with the original name)
- Delete the temporary origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question is about `Az Powershell` however if you have stumbled upon this don't waste your time :). The only way I was able to resolve the this was with `az cli` and the use of `az afd origin create` and `az afd origin update`.

see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/origin?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-origin-create

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/origin?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-origin-update

Answer (score 0):

Issues may arise because of **active connections**. The problem will be resolved if all connections were rejected or deleted before deleting the service.

Usually, front door service is not renewed immediately. Before you delete the service, ensure that there are no private endpoint connections associated with it.

1. Need to delete the Endpoints which links to Private link by using this command

   ```
   Remove-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -Name testendpoint -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ServiceName <privatelinkservice> -PrivateLinkResourceType Microsoft.Network/privateLinkServices
   ```
2. Remove all end points

   ```
   Remove-AzPrivateEndpoint -Name testendpoint -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
   ```
3. Remove private link service from the service.
   `Remove-AzPrivateLinkService -ResourceGroupName rg-swarnaacctestrg -Name privatelinkswarna`
4. From Front Door side, we need to purge the so that changes will reflect/ refresh
   `az afd endpoint purge -g <ResourceGroupName> --profile-name profile --domains <DomainName> --content-paths '/*'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Swarna.  I have tried this out from a FD premium instance with private link connected to an app service and all 4 commands ran ok.  

However it seems that the checkmark remains for private link on the origin record in Front door and the app service still is inaccessible via the front door.

We have a workaround (deleting and recreating the origin) for this so am going to stick with that for now, but thanks again for your time in replying.